# RegExp to Get N words before and after

Tags: php, regex, grep, preg-match

I want to get the "context" of a given search string. For example, for search string `myself` in the following line

> Me, my dog and myself are going on a vacation.

I want to get `dog and myself are going` for N=2. So 2 words before match and 2 after.

---

Currently I match whole lines like this:

```
$lines = file($file->getFilename());
$lines = preg_grep('/'.$_POST['query'].'/', $lines);
```

Comment: How complicated can the file content and the search string be?

Comment: How do you define a "word"? Only English alphabet or including other languages? Do you allow digit? What about punctuation? Or do you rather define it as a non-space sequence?

Comment: Let's assume file content is made up from "words" - strings separated by whitespaces.

Comment: @PrimožKralj If file content is made up of words separated by whitespace, you need to only `explode(' ',$line)`, get rid of the first two and last two elements, and `implode(' ',$array)`. But I doubt your actual situation can be this simple.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[preg_grep()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) is supposed to act like that, but it sounds like you would need [preg_match()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and in case you can have multiple instances of searched word in the text and want to find all of them [preg_match_all()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

The RegEx you're looking for is: `(?:[^ ]+ ){0,2}myself(?: [^ ]+){0,2}`
Explained demo here: http://regex101.com/r/pB3eW0

I designed it to match 2 words before and after *if it can* otherwise 1 word or even none.

The code allowing a variable *N* could look like this:

```
$fileData=file_get_contents($file->getFilename());
$n=2;
$query='myself';
preg_match_all('/(?:[^ ]+ ){0,'.$n.'}'.$query.'(?: [^ ]+){0,'.$n.'}/i',$fileData,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Remember to validate and escape user input** and not just use it in functions as given!

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for introducing to regex101.com its pretty cool.

Comment: Is this also valid for ag?