# Regular expression to capture n words after pattern that do not contain that pattern

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to write a regular expression that captures n words after a pattern, which was [answered in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15586010/6587318), except I want the search to keep going for another n words if it encounters that pattern again. For example,  if my main search pattern is 'x', and I want to capture a word that contains 'x' and n=3 words after it *that don't contain 'x'*, the following string should result in three matches:

> Lorem ipsum dolxor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morxbi fringilla, dui axt tincidunt consectetur, libero arcu cursus arcxu, ut commodo lexctus magna vitxae venenatis neque.

Matches ('x's in bold for ease of viewing)

1. dol**x**or sit amet, consectetur
2. Mor**x**bi fringilla, dui a**x**t tincidunt consectetur, libero
3. arc**x**u, ut commodo le**x**ctus magna vit**x**ae venenatis neque.

Matching n=3 words after is straightforward: `[^ ]*x[^ ]*(?: [^ ]*){0,3}`

How to keep going if another 'x' is encountered, I'm not sure. I've tried this -- `[^ ]*x[^ ]*(?: (?![^ ]*x[^ ]*)[^ ]*){0,3}` -- but it terminates the search instead of continuing on check the next n words, which, given the example above, gives six results instead of the expected three:

1. dol**x**or sit amet, consectetur
2. Mor**x**bi fringilla, dui
3. a**x**t tincidunt consectetur, libero
4. arc**x**u, ut commodo
5. le**x**ctus magna
6. vit**x**ae venenatis neque.

P.S. I'm working with python.

---

EDIT: For context, I'm trying to get sufficient information about the surroundings of each appearance of the given pattern. (For simplicity's sake, I'm only including the words after the pattern, but it's easy to generalize to words in the back.) And the problem with the first regex is that it might result in a word that lacks information on its surroundings if it gets picked up as part of the surroundings of another match. For example, the first match given the text above would be 'Mor**x**bi fringilla, dui a**x**t', which gives us information about what comes after 'Morxbi' but not 'axt'. The second regex doesn't help because now matches with another match in its surroundings will lose that information, e.g., we won't know the third word that comes after 'Morxbi'.

Comment: How about e.g. this demo: [`\bfoo(?:\W+(?!foo\b)\w+){0,3}`](https://regex101.com/r/JOrsHk/3)

Comment: @bobblebubble Thanks for the quick response--it helped me realize I accidentally included a ':' in my second regex, and after removing it, it's basically the same as your suggestion (I'm happy to stick with single spaces as the word delimiter for now, and the search token can be embedded, as shown in the examples). That said, that solution just terminates the search instead of moving on to the next 3 words.

Comment: Welcome! Was just reading your question again and I think you were more after something like [`(?i)(?:\b\w*?x\w*(?:\W+[a-wyz]+\b){0,3}\W*)+(?<!\s)`](https://regex101.com/r/Jtw6K7/1) or more excluding and readable: [`(?i)(?:\b[a-wyz]*x[a-z]*(?:[ ,;.!?]+[a-wyz]+\b){0,3}[ ,;.!?]*)+(?<! )`](https://regex101.com/r/Jtw6K7/2) (the `(?i)` is for *ignoring case* and the *lookbehind* at the end `(?<!\s)` just for not letting the match end with whitespace).

Comment: @bobblebubble Wow that's exactly it!

Comment: You're welcome, glad that helped and I noticed you got it solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the solution was a lot closer than I thought! Since `[^ ]*x[^ ]*(?: (?![^ ]*x[^ ]*)[^ ]*){0,3}` already captures the appropriate strings and the only problem is that it cuts them off instead of joining them (e.g., 'Morxbi fringilla, dui' and 'axt tincidunt consectetur, libero' instead of 'Morxbi fringilla, dui axt tincidunt consectetur, libero'), then the solution would be simply to add a `+` to the overall expression (and accounting for the spaces between them) to join them: `(?:[^ ]*x[^ ]*(?: (?![^ ]*x[^ ]*)[^ ]*){0,3} ?)+(?<! )` ([example](https://regex101.com/r/6o4FTQ/2))

This solution can also be extended to looking for n words before and m words after the pattern: `(?:(?:[^ ]* ){0,n}[^ ]*x[^ ]*(?: (?![^ ]*x[^ ]*)[^ ]*){0,m})+` ([example with n=2 and m=3](https://regex101.com/r/hP3Qsu/2)).

Thanks to @bobblebubble for making this suggestion in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear that regex is the most natural way to solve your use case.
Consider this hybrid approach.

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"x")  # or whatever

def get_at_least_n(text: str, n=3) -> Optional[range]:
    words = text.split()
    matches = list(map(pattern.search, words))
    if not any(matches):
        return None
    last = sorted(_get_ranges(matches, n))[-1]
    _, i, j = last
    assert j >= i + n
    return range(i, j)

def _get_ranges(matches, n):
    for i in range(len(matches)):
        if matches[i]:
            j = i + n
            k = j + 1
            while k < len(matches) and k - j < n:
                if matches[k]:
                    j = k
        yield j - i, i, j
```

The regular expression engine loops over characters
and can handle CFGs, but is not Turing complete.
For one thing, evaluation is guaranteed to always Halt.
(Cheating a bit, wrapping it in a loop such as `sed` offers,
would enable Turing and even Conway's Life: https://bitly.com/regexgol)

Here, the longest match you're looking for could be
supplied in various orders, such as

```
A B x D E x G H x J K L M N O x Q R x T
```

or

```
A B x D E F G H I J K L M N O x Q R x T
```

so the correct answer for (1.) is "x D E x G H x J K"
and for (2.) is "x Q R x T".

Computing longest match using just the regex engine
is not straightforward,
and it would yield illegible code, unmaintainable.

Given that you have cPython's Turing machine available
to you, hey, may as well use it, right?

#### time complexity

Let `m` denote the number of matches, the number of
input words.

It is clear the inner loop executes at most
`m` × `n` times.

So depending on whether you view `n` as constant,
we have either O(`m` × `n`) or O(`m`).

In contrast, "short" regular expressions with [multiple
levels of backtracking](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) can easily
take cubic time or worse.

Comment: This makes sense--thank you! I should have specified in my question that I was not bent on a regex answer and was just curious to see if there was one!